# Sorting file lines per matching pattern

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

**Input**

Here is the file `test.txt`

```
this is row4 row4
row2 xxx row2
row11 // row11
row10 mmm row10
row8row8 fubar
row1row1
row6 and row6
row7 row7
row3row3
/row9 row9
row5  /row5
```

On each row, there is the indication of where the row should be placed. For example, the current row 9 contains the string "row3row3", this means that the row 9 should be placed at position 3. Each row contains exactly twice the indication of where the row should be placed and no two rows have the same index.

**Expected Output**

Here is the expected output on `test2.txt`

```
row1row1    
row2 xxx row2
row3row3
this is row4 row4
row5  /row5
row6 and row6
row7 row7
row8row8 fubar
/row9 row9
row10 mmm row10
row11 // row11
```

Can you help me to sort the file correclty?

**What I tried**

Here is my trial so far. I think I am not too far but there is a bug I fail to find.

```
# Get the rows indication
a=$(grep -o row[0-9]* test.txt | sed s/row//)
a=( $a )

# Remove the double indication
a2=()
for i in $(seq 1 ${#a[@]})
do
[ $(($i%2)) -ne 0 ] && a2+=(${a[i]})
done

# Loop through each row
for row in $(seq 1 ${#a2[@]})
do
    # Search for the row that should be placed at position $row
    for i in "${!a2[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${a2[$i]}" = "${row}" ]]
        then
            # Once the correct row was found, read it and print it on another file
            p=$(sed "${a2[$i]}q;d" test.txt)
            echo $p >> test2.txt
            break
        fi
    done 
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gnu `awk` you can do this in a single command:

```
awk -F '.*row' 'BEGIN {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}
{
   a[$2] = $0
}
END {
   for(k in a)
      print a[k]
}' file
```

- Using custom field separator `.*row` we extract the number after `row` for each line
- Using that number as key we create an array `a` where value is full line
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` is used to sort associative array in ascending numerical order of array index

**Output:**

```
row1row1
row2 xxx row2
row3row3
this is row4 row4
row5  /row5
row6 and row6
row7 row7
row8row8 fubar
/row9 row9
row10 mmm row10
row11 // row11
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code but it did not order the lines perfectly on my computer. The output is in the order `8,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,1`. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I attached output from the the command output of my shell. Are you sure you are using Gnu awk for this?

Comment: If you don't have gnu-awk then use: `awk -F '.*row' '{a[$2]=$0} END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file | sort -nk1 | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Comment: Oh thank you your comment did it. I guess i'd better link gnu-awk by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can always follow decorate/sort/undecorate pattern

```
$ sed -r 's/.*row([0-9]+)/\1\t&/' rows | sort -n | cut -f2-

row1row1
row2 xxx row2
row3row3
this is row4 row4
row5  /row5
row6 and row6
row7 row7
row8row8 fubar
/row9 row9
row10 mmm row10
row11 // row11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't fully understand it yet. Note that the flag `-r` seems to be an illegal option for me. I am also wondering what object is `row`. Is it an array of the rows in the file (the equivalent of my array `a`)?

Comment: that's the regular expression flag to insert the matched regex in '\1` position.  "row" is the prefix for the number which dictates the ordering position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tr -c '0-9\n' ' ' <file | awk '{print $1}' | paste -d " " - file | sort -k1,1n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -nle 'push @a, $_ ; 
 END{print join("\n", map  { $_->[0] }
 sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
 map  { [$_, /(\d+)/] } @a)}' file
```